# simple problems in multi thread in java

Tags: multithreading

I need help to get the answer for this  :

The question asked what is the output of the following codes?

```
package tryScope;
 
public class MyThread extends Thread{
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("MyThread: run()");
    }
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("MyThread: start()");
    }
}
 
class MyRunnable implements Runnable{
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("MyRunnable: run()");
    }
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("MyRunnable: start()");
    }
}
 
public class myTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyThread myThread = new MyThread();
        MyRunnable myRunnable = new MyRunnable();
        Thread thread = new Thread(myRunnable);
        myThread.start();
    }
}
```

So, I am suppose to choose 1 correct answer but I can't even make it run.  I would like to verify if there is something wrong with the code the question is set?

Here are the 4 choices:

1. Prints: MyThread: run() followed by MyRunnable: start()
2. Prints: MyThread: start() followed by MyRunnable:start()
3. Prints: MyThread: run() followed by MyRunnable:run()
4. Prints: MyThread: start() followed by MyRunnable:run()

Please let me know which is the correct answer and if there is something wrong with the code.

Tks.

Comment: None of the above These questions can never have deterministic answers: otherwise why use threads? The only thing you can say with confidence is that `start()` will always precede `run()` for the same object. In this case `MyRunnable` neither starts nor runs at all, so it cannot possibly produce any output whatsoever, and `MyThread` never starts a thread, because `start()` is overridden, so `MyThread.run()` can never run either. So actually there are no threads at all here except the main thread. Strange question.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code is just stupid. The output should be `"MyThread: start()"` and nothing else.

Thats because in the class `MyThread` the start method is overwritten. So there's no Thread starting at all. You can try modify the method like this:

```java
public class MyThread extends Thread{
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("MyThread: run()");
    }
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("MyThread: start()");
        super.start();
    }
}
```

Then the ouput should be something like `"MyThread: start()"` followed by `"MyThread: run()"`

To achieve this:
`MyThread: start() followed by MyRunnable:run()`
add in the main-method the line:

```java
myRunnable.run()
```

Note: You shouldn't override the start method in Thread at all, as mentioned above from [Hejday](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16933393/hejdah-charkh). This method handles the intern creation and starting of the Thread. The Thread will then execute it's run method [see Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start()).

Comment: Re, "The code is just stupid." Looks to me as if the code is from a test. No computers allowed. You're supposed to look at it and say what it does. If you think it's "stupid," then congratulations! You passed the test.

Comment: Re, "You can try modify the method like this..." Nope. Not if you are taking the test. Probably no place on the test sheet for you to write in your revised program. And even if you wrote it in the margin, it might not be scored as a correct answer.

Comment: I guess "The code is just stupid" wasn't the best phrasing. I'm aware, that it is a test and not a code, which has any usecase. So the correct answer to the question would be "None of these choices".

Comment: With the modify part, I tried to explain, what is happening.